# jQuery Change background URL of the body with fade Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, fade

I gave the body a class `.wrapbgone` and I am switching the class after X seconds to `.wrapbgtwo`.

I want the switching to appear with fade effect.

This is my CSS:

```
.wrapbgone{background:url('http://placehold.it/500x500/915');height:100%;}
.wrapbgtwo{background:url('http://placehold.it/500x500/400');height:1580px;}
```

and here is the example: http://jsbin.com/ebemez/4/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're swapping a class, you can't fade it to the best of my knowledge (you can cycle background colours - see the header of http://www.made-by-mike.co.uk), but not images.

The best solution I can think of is to nest two absolutely-positioned divs in the root level of your document (before your content div):

```
<body>
    <div id="bgone">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="bgtwo">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="content">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Then use jQuery to fade one in over the other:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bgtwo').fadeTo(0,0); // or set opacity to 0 in CSS to prevent div appearing then disappearing on page load
    $('#bgtwo').fadeTo(500, 1, function(){
        $('#bgone').remove(); // replace remove() with fadeTo(500,0) if you don't want to remove it from the page altogether
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this using the background image css property on the body class.

You would need to create a container for the second background image and a container for the page content, place them over each other and then you can fade the background container in and out so the image will crossfade to/from the original body background image.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is built into the core of jQueryUI.  It is a function called switchClass (basically could very easily have been called animateClass).  It's great; facilitates smooth animation of elements based on a current and future class (removes/adds these classes for you auto-magically) and supports easing transitions, transition time, and a callback fxn.  Hope it helps, I use it to transition my gallery menu on my site.